# HelloSign bundle not working in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, hellosign-api

I have installed the Hello Sign PHP SDK in a Symfony project and it does not work and requesting to add a "use" statement which I added and still not working. (https://github.com/HelloFax/hellosign-php-sdk)

This is the error I get when I used SDK

> Attempted to load class "Client" from namespace
>   "AppBundle\Controller\HelloSign". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   e.g. "HelloSign\Client", "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client",
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client",
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client" or "GuzzleHttp\Client"

Then I used a PHP wrapper for Hello Sign called "bukashk0zzz/hellosign-bundle". And that too is requesting to add a "use" statement which I added but not working. (https://github.com/Bukashk0zzz/HelloSignBundle)

Here's that error.

> Attempted to load class "TemplateSignatureRequest" from namespace
>   "AppBundle\Controller\HelloSign". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   "HelloSign\TemplateSignatureRequest"?

My code is

```
require_once('../vendor/hellosign/hellosign-php-sdk/vendor/autoload.php');
$client = new HelloSign\Client('apikey');
$account = $client->getAccount();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show your code where you are getting this error.

Comment: @AmitMerchant I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$client = new \HelloSign\Client('apikey');
$account = $client->getAccount();
```

*if `hellosign-php-sdk` is installed with composer*

Answer (score 1):

Hellosign has API developer support at apisupport@hellosign.com if you have any other questions. Please feel free to reach out there as well. Sounds like you got your answer though.